# What is the difference between FirebaseAuth and FirebaseUser classes' uid property?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

When getting the current auth user ID from firebase on Android, what is the difference between getting it from the `FirebaseAuth` or the `FirebaseUser` class?

For example:

```
val uid1 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
val uid2 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid
```

They seem to return the same value, is there any reason or use case to choose one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine the bytecode very carefully, you will see that `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()` is implemented (essentially) like this:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
return user == null ? null : user.getUid();
```

They are basically the same thing.  Just use the one that you personally prefer.

I will point out, however, that `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()` does not show up anywhere in the documentation.  So it doesn't seem like the recommended choice in any circumstance.

Comment: I see, it's a shortcut in the FirebaseAuth class. Thanks.